# What lib is usually to be used to develop a simple game like Tetris?

Tags: c

I am going to develop a Tetris in practice. But I have no idea how to start it, especially the graphic part - how to draw the frame and blocks? how to move them on screen?
Could you please you refer me to some useful libs or tools?

Programming language is c. (if this is done, I am planing to do it again with c++ and python. :) Both Windows or Unix-like is ok. It's better if it is portable.

I know openGL, and DirectX is heavy-weight lib. dose it efficiently fit to a small game like Tetris? Any light-weight? which is better?

I would appreciate if you could refer me to some materials or links for this.

Thanks.

Comment: At least for normal (2D) Tetris, I see little reason to use either DirectX or OpenGL. Almost anything that supports (for example) blitting bitmaps would be entirely adequate.

Comment: Using OpenGL and DirectX you can probably build anything and everything... If you want to develop the game in a single day you should go for XNA.

Comment: ncurses is about as light-weight as you can get with graphics libraries. And having read an OS tutorial yesterday: if you manage to keep the flat binary below 512 bytes, you could finally put the MBR to good use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep your game in a window and not full-screen, then any library that implements some type of paintable canvas widget will work.  Cross-platform candidates include [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/), [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), etc.  If you want to remain on a single platform like Windows, then you can use a lower-level Win32 API like [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  As I mentioned in my first sentence, with most of these libraries/API's, you'd be looking to use their paintable canvas widgets, allowing you to draw the characters shapes on the window.  You'd also use some type of timer event to periodically update the drawn window at fixed time intervals.

Comment: GTK+ runs natively on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SDL - is simple and many platforms are supported

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) or [Allegro](http://www.allegro.cc/). Both provide simple ways of getting input and doing graphics and audio output. And both are multiplatform.

Comment: Thanks. The first of SDL application on its homepage is just a Tetris. :-)